# Append quotation

Tags: jquery

I am trying to `append()` a button with an `onclick` attribute which calls a javascript function:

```
$('#button').append('<button onclick=setUrlLink(\''+pageN+'\')>Next</button>);
```

When checking the source code, quotations are missing around `pageN`, how can I do that?

Comment: I tried your example, but it fails, i added a screenshot to show it.

Comment: Your original append statement should work if you add the double quoters around the onclick value `$('#button').append('<button onclick="setUrlLink(\''+pageN+'\')">Next</button>);` I added that as well as the alternative of using double quotes outside and singles inside to an answer with a DEMO. I would recommend in general to specify the quotes around the onclick value i.e: `onclick="..."` instead of relying on anything else to do it automatically, that way you should have no unexpected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use **Double Quotes**

```
$('#button').append('<button onclick=setUrlLink("'+pageN+'")>Next</button>');
                                            ----^         ^---
```

Comment: Don't forget the quote at the end of the string. ;)

Comment: @JasonTowne.. Thanks Missed that

Comment: I just did that, but it does not work...

I will make a screenshot of the exact thing...

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use jQuery to do that?

```
$("#button").append($("<button>").on('click', function () { setUrlLink('pageN'); })
   .text('Next'));
```

Comment: please check my screenshot (edit) + your code gives me : `<button>Next</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Just use double quotes to start the string instead of single quotes.

```
$("#button").append("<button onclick=setUrlLink('" +pageN+ "')>Next</button>");
```